# Combine ajax requests in one template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, business-catalyst

I have 2 Ajax request to GET some CRM details, firstly I would like to get all the **orders statuses** in the system create a container with an ID for each one of the statuses and get all the orders pulled from another request and **place them in each STATUSES ID container**.

Found difficulty to loop through the statuses and orders and place them accordingly.

**Code**

```
function createOrderStatuses(){
  var access_token = BCAPI.Helper.Site.getAccessToken();
  var request = $.ajax({
      url: "/webresources/api/v3/sites/current/orderstatuses",
      type: "GET",
      connection: "keep-alive",    
      contentType: "application/json",
      headers: _authorization
  });
  request.done(function (msg) {
      console.log(msg);
      //var orderStatusesArray = msg[];
      for (var i = 0; i < msg.items.length; i++){
           var statuses = msg.items[i];
           var statusTemplate = '<div class="large-12 columns margin-distributed statusClass" id="'+ statuses.id +'"><h4 class="lato-bold">' + statuses.label  + '</h4></div>';

      if (statuses.label !== "EXCHANGE FEE PAID"){
        $("#ordersContainer").append(statusTemplate);
      }else{
        //$(".orderStatuses").append('<option value="'+ statuses.id +'">' + statuses.label  + '</option>');
      }
    }//looping and displaying statuses

   getOrders();

  });//request END


  function getOrders(){

     var access_token = BCAPI.Helper.Site.getAccessToken();
     var request = $.ajax({
         url: "/webresources/api/v3/sites/current/orders",
         type: "GET",
         connection: "keep-alive",    
         contentType: "application/json",
         headers: _authorization
     });
     request.done(function (msg) {
         console.log(msg);
         var containerID = $('.statusClass').each(function(){ $(this).attr('id'); });

         for (var i = 0; i < msg.items.length; i++){
           var orders = msg.items[i];

           var orderTemplate = '<div class="large-12 columns margin-distributed '+ orders.statusTypeId +'"><h5>' + orders.name  + '</h5></div>';
           var orderTemplateClass = orderTemplate.find('div[class*="'+orders.statusTypeId+'"]');

           if  ( orderTemplateClass === containerID ){          
                       $(containerID).append(orderTemplate); 
               }// end IF       

    }//looping orders

     }); 
  }//GET ORDERS END


 }
 createOrderStatuses();
```

Comment: Are you trying to compare orders.statusTypeId with stasuses.id?

Comment: yes, I basically want to compare if the orders.statusTypeId match with the  stasuses.id and place the orders inside of each div with its own status id

Comment: I had some errors because i was trying to run a function inside a foorLoop so I changed to $.each on the response

Comment: $.each is correct but your target selection is wrong. I added an answer, see if it works

Comment: sorry, i was wrong; you don't need $.each. I don't know why i said so. I am deleting containerID line from answer.

Comment: your answer is more suitable when using "for" because functions are not allowed inside a "for" I changed my code to $.each in case i need to run a more specific function later more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the target status container div with this: `$("#ordersContainer .statusClass[id="+orders.statusTypeId+"]")`

Here is the full code of getOrders() function:

```
function getOrders(){

     var access_token = BCAPI.Helper.Site.getAccessToken();
     var request = $.ajax({
         url: "/webresources/api/v3/sites/current/orders",
         type: "GET",
         connection: "keep-alive",    
         contentType: "application/json",
         headers: _authorization
     });
     request.done(function (msg) {
         console.log(msg);

         for (var i = 0; i < msg.items.length; i++){
           var orders = msg.items[i];

           var orderTemplate = '<div class="large-12 columns margin-distributed '+ orders.statusTypeId +'"><h5>' + orders.name  + '</h5></div>';


    $("#ordersContainer .statusClass[id="+orders.statusTypeId+"]").append(orderTemplate)



    }//looping orders

     }); 
  }//GET ORDERS END


 }
```